# Dot Notation Alternatives

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering if there is an alternative to dot notation in C#. For instance, in Javascript, I can have an object like this:

```
const myObj = { foo: "bar" }
```

And then I can reference it like this:

```
let x = "foo";
let y = myObj[x]; //sets y = "bar"
```

Is this possible in C#? I have not found anything of the sort, but am wondering if there are alternatives that would function similarly.

Comment: Nothing that wouldn't involve things like reflection, boxing, `object` Dictionaries, or something like that.  And even then wouldn't be anywhere near as simple as in JavaScript.  Basically, nothing that would be reasonable for writing stable and supportable C# code.  Why on Earth would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @David - I am following along a Udemy course where we are making a 2d space shooter. You can gain powerup to get abilities, which are then disabled after X seconds. I was attempting to make a single function that handled the disabling of all possible powerups by passing the powerup name through as a string, then using something like:
player[powerUpName] = false;

Comment: JavaScript objects are essentially just dictionaries.  C# has [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) and you can make Lists of [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.2).  Not sure if this is too simplistic for what you are needing but it's an option.  The only issue is that they can only hold a single value type unless you want to cast the value to a type everytime you retrieve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement an indexer in your class:

```
public class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public string Y { get; set; }

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get => GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(this, null);
        set => GetType().GetProperty(name).SetValue(this, value);
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
var a = new A();
a["X"] = 10;
a["Y"] = "abc";

Console.WriteLine(a.X);
Console.WriteLine(a.Y);
```

Comment: I didn't realize that your solution was complete until I wrote mine… Your code is much simpler if properties are fixed.

Comment: Nice answer to question as asked... Also based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623080/dot-notation-alternatives#comment96038830_54623080) OP actually needs dictionary of named "powerups", but that is very different from what they asked.

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk, thank you for this solution. I will do my best to implement it - though I am still very new at C#. Your (along with everyone else's) help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can have something similar using `dynamic` but you have to explicitly get the dictionary interface to use the array syntax.

```
dynamic myObject = new ExpandoObject();
myObject.greeting = "hello";

IDictionary<string, object> myDict = myObject;
Console.WriteLine(myDict["greeting"]);
```

Note that it works in both directions. You can add that after the previous code:

```
myDict["name"] = "Joe";
Console.WriteLine(myObject.name);
```

You can have both syntax if you don't mind having an intermediate object like `myObject.something.name`.

The code would look like:

```
void Main()
{
    BothSyntax test= new BothSyntax();
    test.dyn.greeting = "Hi";

    Console.WriteLine(test["greeting"]);

    test["name"] = "Joe";
    Console.WriteLine(test.dyn.name);
}

class BothSyntax
{
    public dynamic dyn => eo;
    private ExpandoObject eo = new ExpandoObject();
    public object this[string key] 
    { 
        get
    {
            return ((IDictionary<string, object>)eo)[key];
        }
        set
        {
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)eo)[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```